# White coloured text and spacing of gaps

Tags: text, publishing

I want to produce 'gap texts' with LaTeX. What happens, when I colour something white, and then print it? Would it still get printed?

What I have in mind is something like this:

```
Here is a \color{white}{blank} to fill in.
```

Would other methods be more more suitable, like `~` or `\quad`?
Just whitening the text would mean to automatically have the right space for the blank as an indication.

Comment: A white text is unreadable, unless the background is coloured.

Comment: You may wish to consider the package [censor](https://ctan.org/pkg/censor). You can easily modify the default black blocks to be white.

Comment: `\phantom{blank}` does what you want (i.e., it prints space the size of the argument but doesn't actually print the argument) but this would not be suitable for an exercise on paper (because writing with a pen is always larger than print) and it is not suitable for electronic entry either (because then you need a form field that can actually be filled). If you want to actually censor/anonymize a text then indeed the `censor` package may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want the blanks in your text? The "exam" document class is great for fill in the  blank questions, if you are making a quiz. A MWE:

```
    \documentclass{exam}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question The magic word is \fillin[prestidigitator][2in].
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

Using the option `answers`, you can generate the answers to the quiz:

```
    \documentclass[answers]{exam}
    ...
```

BTW, if your using the white color trick and want to hide the answer, make sure that the pdf does not contain the answer in white. Selecting the text in the pdf will let you see if it is there or not.

If you just want a blank in a document other than a quiz, you can simply use `\makebox[5cm]{}` to leave the blank space. For the exact length of a word or phrase, you can use the `calc` package and write:

```
    \makebox[\widthof{phrase or word}]{}
```

I hope that this answer is what you need.

Comment: Thank  you for this answer.